# testing a service that uses a third party library

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a `Service` that uses a library called `client`.

The `Client` class that I load is stored in the private property `client` of `Service`.

For my spec,  I can't inject `mockClient` in my Service like this

```
service = new Service(mockClient)
```

but I can't either do

```
service = new Service()
service.client = mockClient
```

since `client` is private.

What is the right practice to test a service that uses a third party library that is not injected and that you want to mock ?

Edit: 
my service uses a third party lib like this

```
import { Client } from 'someLib';

Injectable()
export class Service {
  private client: Client;

  constructor() {
    this.client = new Client();
  }
```

Comment: Could you give a less abstract example? Why can't you use DI to provide a mock?

Comment: I edited my post with the service class. I can't use DI because the third party lib isn't injected.

Comment: You could refactor so that it *is* injected, then the testing will be easier.

Answer (score 0):

The proper practice here is to refactor your code so that your third party library is injected.  First, you should wrap the library in a service or a factory. As a bonus, you may want to only expose the parts of the third party library that you are using. You can validate parameters in your service and transform them so that the call signatures make sense for your app.  So, it may look something like this:

```
app.service('theirLibraryFactory', () => {
 return {
   createClientWrapper: () => {
      let client = new Client();
      return {
        op1: (args) => client.doOp1(args),
        op2: (args) => client.doOp2(args)
        ...
      }
 };  
}
```

With this client wrapper, you can then inject it into your classes, and then mock it.

ps- I *know* that angualarjs provides factories as a base type, but I prefer to use services since they do everything that factories do, but more explicitly. YMMV.